# How add ArrayList to listview1 in c#

Tags: c#, .net, listview, arraylist

I have an ArrayList

```
...    
while (reader.Read())
{
        decimal nr_zbor = reader.GetDecimal(cod_zbor);
        string airport = reader.GetString(name_aeroport);
        string company = reader.GetString(name_company);
        list.Add(nr_zbor);
        list.Add(airport);
        list.Add(company);
}
...
```

and I wish to put in the listview **columns[zbor,airport,company]**, but I don't now how

```
fly = searchFly.GetFly(direction, country, theDate, DFlexible);
```

can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create a class with those 3 properties

```
class nac
{
   public decimal nr_zbor ...
   public string airport ...
   public string company ...
}

List<nac> nacs = new List<nac>();
```

Those properties are the columns

[ListView Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`ListViewItems` may contain `ListViewSubItems`. The **item itself** will be shown in the **first column**, **after** that **all subItems** will be shown. So you may adapt your code to

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    decimal nr_zbor = reader.GetDecimal(cod_zbor);
    string airport = reader.GetString(name_aeroport);
    string company = reader.GetString(name_company);

    ListViewItem newItem = new ListViewItem(nr_zbor.ToString());
    newItem.SubItems.Add(airport);
    newItem.SubItems.Add(company);

    list.Items.Add(newItem); // assuming list is your listView
}
```

Make sure you set your **ListView** to `View.Details` so that columns will show up.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
while(....)
{
   .........
   listview.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(nr_zbor), new ListViewItem(airport),new      
   ListViewItem(company);
}
```

I have not tested it.